# EventService timed out after:3000

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I'm invoking my chaincode via node-sdk by queueing the submissions via the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) package. However, I very often get a `error: [EventService]: EventService[org1-peer1] timed out after:3000`. There's no additional information at the peer's log. The transaction is getting processed, though.

Here's the **client log** (GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG, GRPC_TRACE=all):

```
--> Starting task
2020-08-13T08:49:36.081Z | call_stream | [2] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.083Z | call_stream | [2] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.083Z | call_stream | [2] parsed message of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.084Z | call_stream | [2] filterReceivedMessage of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.084Z | call_stream | [2] pushing to reader message of length 1471
2020-08-13T08:49:36.088Z | call_stream | [2] Received server trailers:
                grpc-status: 0
                grpc-message:

2020-08-13T08:49:36.088Z | call_stream | [2] received status code 0 from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.088Z | call_stream | [2] received status details string "" from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.089Z | call_stream | [2] ended with status: code=0 details=""
2020-08-13T08:49:36.090Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30171 callRefcount 3 -> 2
2020-08-13T08:49:36.090Z | call_stream | [2] HTTP/2 stream closed with code 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.098Z | call_stream | [8] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.099Z | call_stream | [8] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.099Z | call_stream | [8] parsed message of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.099Z | call_stream | [8] filterReceivedMessage of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.099Z | call_stream | [8] pushing to reader message of length 1471
2020-08-13T08:49:36.100Z | call_stream | [8] Received server trailers:
                grpc-status: 0
                grpc-message:

2020-08-13T08:49:36.100Z | call_stream | [8] received status code 0 from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.100Z | call_stream | [8] received status details string "" from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.100Z | call_stream | [8] ended with status: code=0 details=""
2020-08-13T08:49:36.101Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30171 callRefcount 2 -> 1
2020-08-13T08:49:36.101Z | call_stream | [8] HTTP/2 stream closed with code 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.101Z | call_stream | [5] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.101Z | call_stream | [5] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.101Z | call_stream | [5] parsed message of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.101Z | call_stream | [5] filterReceivedMessage of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.102Z | call_stream | [5] pushing to reader message of length 1471
2020-08-13T08:49:36.102Z | call_stream | [5] Received server trailers:
                grpc-status: 0
                grpc-message:

2020-08-13T08:49:36.102Z | call_stream | [5] received status code 0 from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.102Z | call_stream | [5] received status details string "" from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.102Z | call_stream | [5] ended with status: code=0 details=""
2020-08-13T08:49:36.102Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30171 callRefcount 1 -> 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.102Z | call_stream | [5] HTTP/2 stream closed with code 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.103Z | call_stream | [6] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.103Z | call_stream | [6] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.103Z | call_stream | [6] parsed message of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.103Z | call_stream | [6] filterReceivedMessage of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.103Z | call_stream | [6] pushing to reader message of length 1471
2020-08-13T08:49:36.103Z | call_stream | [6] Received server trailers:
                grpc-status: 0
                grpc-message:

2020-08-13T08:49:36.103Z | call_stream | [6] received status code 0 from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.103Z | call_stream | [6] received status details string "" from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.103Z | call_stream | [6] ended with status: code=0 details=""
2020-08-13T08:49:36.104Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 callRefcount 3 -> 2
2020-08-13T08:49:36.104Z | call_stream | [6] HTTP/2 stream closed with code 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.104Z | call_stream | [0] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.104Z | call_stream | [0] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.104Z | call_stream | [0] parsed message of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.104Z | call_stream | [0] filterReceivedMessage of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.104Z | call_stream | [0] pushing to reader message of length 1472
2020-08-13T08:49:36.104Z | call_stream | [0] Received server trailers:
                grpc-status: 0
                grpc-message:

2020-08-13T08:49:36.104Z | call_stream | [0] received status code 0 from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.104Z | call_stream | [0] received status details string "" from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.105Z | call_stream | [0] ended with status: code=0 details=""
2020-08-13T08:49:36.105Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 callRefcount 2 -> 1
2020-08-13T08:49:36.105Z | call_stream | [0] HTTP/2 stream closed with code 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.105Z | call_stream | [3] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.105Z | call_stream | [3] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.105Z | call_stream | [3] parsed message of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.105Z | call_stream | [3] filterReceivedMessage of length 1476
2020-08-13T08:49:36.106Z | call_stream | [3] pushing to reader message of length 1471
2020-08-13T08:49:36.106Z | call_stream | [3] Received server trailers:
                grpc-status: 0
                grpc-message:

2020-08-13T08:49:36.106Z | call_stream | [3] received status code 0 from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.106Z | call_stream | [3] received status details string "" from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.106Z | call_stream | [3] ended with status: code=0 details=""
2020-08-13T08:49:36.106Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 callRefcount 1 -> 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.106Z | call_stream | [3] HTTP/2 stream closed with code 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.107Z | call_stream | [7] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.107Z | call_stream | [7] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.107Z | call_stream | [7] parsed message of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.107Z | call_stream | [7] filterReceivedMessage of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.107Z | call_stream | [7] pushing to reader message of length 1472
2020-08-13T08:49:36.107Z | call_stream | [7] Received server trailers:
                grpc-status: 0
                grpc-message:

2020-08-13T08:49:36.107Z | call_stream | [7] received status code 0 from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.107Z | call_stream | [7] received status details string "" from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.108Z | call_stream | [7] ended with status: code=0 details=""
2020-08-13T08:49:36.108Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30161 callRefcount 3 -> 2
2020-08-13T08:49:36.108Z | call_stream | [7] HTTP/2 stream closed with code 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.116Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 IDLE -> IDLE
2020-08-13T08:49:36.116Z | connectivity_state | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 IDLE -> IDLE
2020-08-13T08:49:36.116Z | dns_resolver | Resolver constructed for target dns:worker2.example.com:30151
2020-08-13T08:49:36.117Z | call_stream | [1] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.117Z | call_stream | [1] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.117Z | call_stream | [1] parsed message of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.117Z | call_stream | [1] filterReceivedMessage of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.117Z | call_stream | [1] pushing to reader message of length 1472
2020-08-13T08:49:36.117Z | call_stream | [1] Received server trailers:
                grpc-status: 0
                grpc-message:

2020-08-13T08:49:36.117Z | call_stream | [1] received status code 0 from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.118Z | call_stream | [1] received status details string "" from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.118Z | call_stream | [1] ended with status: code=0 details=""
2020-08-13T08:49:36.118Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30161 callRefcount 2 -> 1
2020-08-13T08:49:36.118Z | call_stream | [1] HTTP/2 stream closed with code 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.122Z | dns_resolver | Resolution update requested for target dns:worker2.example.com:30151
2020-08-13T08:49:36.122Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 IDLE -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.122Z | connectivity_state | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 IDLE -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.122Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.122Z | connectivity_state | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.132Z | dns_resolver | Resolved addresses for target dns:worker2.example.com:30151: [10.100.136.32:30151]
2020-08-13T08:49:36.132Z | pick_first | IDLE -> IDLE
2020-08-13T08:49:36.132Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> IDLE
2020-08-13T08:49:36.132Z | connectivity_state | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> IDLE
2020-08-13T08:49:36.132Z | dns_resolver | Resolution update requested for target dns:worker2.example.com:30151
2020-08-13T08:49:36.132Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 IDLE -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.132Z | connectivity_state | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 IDLE -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.133Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.133Z | connectivity_state | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.133Z | pick_first | Connect to address list 10.100.136.32:30151
2020-08-13T08:49:36.134Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 refcount 0 -> 1
2020-08-13T08:49:36.135Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 refcount 1 -> 2
2020-08-13T08:49:36.135Z | pick_first | Start connecting to subchannel with address 10.100.136.32:30151
2020-08-13T08:49:36.135Z | pick_first | IDLE -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.135Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.135Z | connectivity_state | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.135Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 IDLE -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.135Z | pick_first | CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.135Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.135Z | connectivity_state | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.136Z | call_stream | [4] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.136Z | call_stream | [4] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.136Z | call_stream | [4] parsed message of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.137Z | call_stream | [4] filterReceivedMessage of length 1477
2020-08-13T08:49:36.137Z | call_stream | [4] pushing to reader message of length 1472
2020-08-13T08:49:36.137Z | call_stream | [4] Received server trailers:
                grpc-status: 0
                grpc-message:

2020-08-13T08:49:36.137Z | call_stream | [4] received status code 0 from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.137Z | call_stream | [4] received status details string "" from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.137Z | call_stream | [4] ended with status: code=0 details=""
2020-08-13T08:49:36.137Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30161 callRefcount 1 -> 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.137Z | call_stream | [4] HTTP/2 stream closed with code 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.142Z | dns_resolver | Resolved addresses for target dns:worker2.example.com:30151: [10.100.136.32:30151]
2020-08-13T08:49:36.142Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 refcount 2 -> 1
2020-08-13T08:49:36.142Z | pick_first | Connect to address list 10.100.136.32:30151
2020-08-13T08:49:36.142Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 refcount 1 -> 2
2020-08-13T08:49:36.142Z | pick_first | CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.143Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.143Z | connectivity_state | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> CONNECTING
2020-08-13T08:49:36.237Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 CONNECTING -> READY
2020-08-13T08:49:36.237Z | pick_first | Pick subchannel with address 10.100.136.32:30151
2020-08-13T08:49:36.237Z | pick_first | CONNECTING -> READY
2020-08-13T08:49:36.237Z | resolving_load_balancer | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> READY
2020-08-13T08:49:36.237Z | connectivity_state | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 CONNECTING -> READY
2020-08-13T08:49:36.237Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 refcount 2 -> 3
2020-08-13T08:49:36.237Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 refcount 3 -> 2
2020-08-13T08:49:36.239Z | channel | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 createCall [9] method="/protos.Deliver/DeliverFiltered", deadline=Infinity
2020-08-13T08:49:36.239Z | call_stream | [9] Sending metadata
2020-08-13T08:49:36.239Z | channel | Pick result: COMPLETE subchannel: 10.100.136.32:30151 status: undefined undefined
2020-08-13T08:49:36.240Z | call_stream | [9] write() called with message of length 1111
2020-08-13T08:49:36.241Z | channel | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 createCall [10] method="/protos.Deliver/DeliverFiltered", deadline=Infinity
2020-08-13T08:49:36.241Z | call_stream | [10] Sending metadata
2020-08-13T08:49:36.241Z | channel | Pick result: COMPLETE subchannel: 10.100.136.32:30151 status: undefined undefined
2020-08-13T08:49:36.241Z | call_stream | [10] write() called with message of length 1110
2020-08-13T08:49:36.241Z | call_stream | [9] deferring writing data chunk of length 1116
2020-08-13T08:49:36.241Z | call_stream | [10] deferring writing data chunk of length 1115
2020-08-13T08:49:36.241Z | subchannel | Starting stream with headers
                grpc-accept-encoding: identity,deflate,gzip
                accept-encoding: identity,gzip
                :authority: worker2.example.com
                user-agent: grpc-node-js/1.0.3
                content-type: application/grpc
                :method: POST
                :path: /protos.Deliver/DeliverFiltered
                te: trailers

2020-08-13T08:49:36.241Z | call_stream | [9] attachHttp2Stream from subchannel 10.100.136.32:30151
2020-08-13T08:49:36.241Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 callRefcount 0 -> 1
2020-08-13T08:49:36.241Z | call_stream | [9] sending data chunk of length 1116 (deferred)
2020-08-13T08:49:36.242Z | subchannel | Starting stream with headers
                grpc-accept-encoding: identity,deflate,gzip
                accept-encoding: identity,gzip
                :authority: worker2.example.com
                user-agent: grpc-node-js/1.0.3
                content-type: application/grpc
                :method: POST
                :path: /protos.Deliver/DeliverFiltered
                te: trailers

2020-08-13T08:49:36.242Z | call_stream | [10] attachHttp2Stream from subchannel 10.100.136.32:30151
2020-08-13T08:49:36.242Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 callRefcount 1 -> 2
2020-08-13T08:49:36.242Z | call_stream | [10] sending data chunk of length 1115 (deferred)
2020-08-13T08:49:36.242Z | channel | dns:worker2.example.com:30151 createCall [11] method="/protos.Deliver/DeliverFiltered", deadline=Infinity
2020-08-13T08:49:36.243Z | call_stream | [11] Sending metadata
2020-08-13T08:49:36.243Z | channel | Pick result: COMPLETE subchannel: 10.100.136.32:30151 status: undefined undefined
2020-08-13T08:49:36.243Z | call_stream | [11] write() called with message of length 1111
2020-08-13T08:49:36.243Z | call_stream | [11] deferring writing data chunk of length 1116
2020-08-13T08:49:36.243Z | subchannel | Starting stream with headers
                grpc-accept-encoding: identity,deflate,gzip
                accept-encoding: identity,gzip
                :authority: worker2.example.com
                user-agent: grpc-node-js/1.0.3
                content-type: application/grpc
                :method: POST
                :path: /protos.Deliver/DeliverFiltered
                te: trailers

2020-08-13T08:49:36.243Z | call_stream | [11] attachHttp2Stream from subchannel 10.100.136.32:30151
2020-08-13T08:49:36.243Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30151 callRefcount 2 -> 3
2020-08-13T08:49:36.243Z | call_stream | [11] sending data chunk of length 1116 (deferred)
2020-08-13T08:49:36.273Z | call_stream | [9] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.273Z | call_stream | [9] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 164
2020-08-13T08:49:36.274Z | call_stream | [9] parsed message of length 164
2020-08-13T08:49:36.274Z | call_stream | [9] filterReceivedMessage of length 164
2020-08-13T08:49:36.274Z | call_stream | [9] pushing to reader message of length 159
2020-08-13T08:49:36.279Z | call_stream | [11] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.279Z | call_stream | [11] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 164
2020-08-13T08:49:36.279Z | call_stream | [11] parsed message of length 164
2020-08-13T08:49:36.279Z | call_stream | [11] filterReceivedMessage of length 164
2020-08-13T08:49:36.279Z | call_stream | [11] pushing to reader message of length 159
2020-08-13T08:49:36.286Z | channel | dns:worker2.example.com:30011 createCall [12] method="/orderer.AtomicBroadcast/Broadcast", deadline=Infinity
2020-08-13T08:49:36.286Z | call_stream | [12] Sending metadata
2020-08-13T08:49:36.286Z | channel | Pick result: COMPLETE subchannel: 10.100.136.32:30011 status: undefined undefined
2020-08-13T08:49:36.287Z | call_stream | [12] write() called with message of length 5483
2020-08-13T08:49:36.287Z | call_stream | [12] deferring writing data chunk of length 5488
2020-08-13T08:49:36.287Z | subchannel | Starting stream with headers
                grpc-accept-encoding: identity,deflate,gzip
                accept-encoding: identity,gzip
                :authority: worker2.example.com
                user-agent: grpc-node-js/1.0.3
                content-type: application/grpc
                :method: POST
                :path: /orderer.AtomicBroadcast/Broadcast
                te: trailers

2020-08-13T08:49:36.287Z | call_stream | [12] attachHttp2Stream from subchannel 10.100.136.32:30011
2020-08-13T08:49:36.287Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30011 callRefcount 0 -> 1
2020-08-13T08:49:36.287Z | call_stream | [12] sending data chunk of length 5488 (deferred)
2020-08-13T08:49:36.287Z | call_stream | [10] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.287Z | call_stream | [10] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 164
2020-08-13T08:49:36.287Z | call_stream | [10] parsed message of length 164
2020-08-13T08:49:36.287Z | call_stream | [10] filterReceivedMessage of length 164
2020-08-13T08:49:36.288Z | call_stream | [10] pushing to reader message of length 159
2020-08-13T08:49:36.315Z | call_stream | [12] Received server headers:
                :status: 200
                content-type: application/grpc

2020-08-13T08:49:36.315Z | call_stream | [12] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 8
2020-08-13T08:49:36.316Z | call_stream | [12] parsed message of length 8
2020-08-13T08:49:36.316Z | call_stream | [12] filterReceivedMessage of length 8
2020-08-13T08:49:36.316Z | call_stream | [12] pushing to reader message of length 3
2020-08-13T08:49:36.319Z | call_stream | [12] end() called
2020-08-13T08:49:36.319Z | call_stream | [12] calling end() on HTTP/2 stream
2020-08-13T08:49:36.351Z | call_stream | [12] Received server trailers:
                grpc-status: 0
                grpc-message:

2020-08-13T08:49:36.351Z | call_stream | [12] received status code 0 from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.352Z | call_stream | [12] received status details string "" from server
2020-08-13T08:49:36.352Z | call_stream | [12] ended with status: code=0 details=""
2020-08-13T08:49:36.352Z | subchannel | 10.100.136.32:30011 callRefcount 1 -> 0
2020-08-13T08:49:36.352Z | call_stream | [12] cancelWithStatus code: 1 details: "Cancelled on client"
2020-08-13T08:49:36.352Z | call_stream | [12] ended with status: code=1 details="Cancelled on client"
2020-08-13T08:49:36.352Z | call_stream | [12] HTTP/2 stream closed with code 0
2020-08-13T08:49:38.336Z | call_stream | [10] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 91
2020-08-13T08:49:38.336Z | call_stream | [10] parsed message of length 91
2020-08-13T08:49:38.336Z | call_stream | [10] filterReceivedMessage of length 91
2020-08-13T08:49:38.336Z | call_stream | [10] pushing to reader message of length 86
2020-08-13T08:49:38.336Z | call_stream | [9] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 91
2020-08-13T08:49:38.336Z | call_stream | [9] parsed message of length 91
2020-08-13T08:49:38.336Z | call_stream | [9] filterReceivedMessage of length 91
2020-08-13T08:49:38.336Z | call_stream | [9] pushing to reader message of length 86
2020-08-13T08:49:38.337Z | call_stream | [11] receive HTTP/2 data frame of length 91
2020-08-13T08:49:38.337Z | call_stream | [11] parsed message of length 91
2020-08-13T08:49:38.337Z | call_stream | [11] filterReceivedMessage of length 91
2020-08-13T08:49:38.337Z | call_stream | [11] pushing to reader message of length 86
2020-08-13T08:49:39.240Z - error: [EventService]: EventService[org1-peer1] timed out after:3000
2020-08-13T08:49:39.241Z - error: [EventService]: send[org1-peer1] - #1 - Starting stream to org1-peer1 failed
```

**Client code:**

```js
'use strict';
const FabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client');
const { Wallets, Gateway } = require('fabric-network');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const async = require("async");

const user = 'benchmark';
const userpw = 'benchmarkPW';
const mspID = 'Org1MSP';
const BENCHMARK_CONCURRENCY = 1;
const BENCHMARK_OPERATIONS = 3;

const txQueue = async.queue(async (task) => {
  console.log('--> Starting task');
  await task;
}, BENCHMARK_CONCURRENCY);

const connectionPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'gateway/connection.yaml');
const data = fs.readFileSync(connectionPath);
const ccp = yaml.safeLoad(data);

async function createWallet() {
  try {
    const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'identity/wallet');
    const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
    return wallet;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
  }
}

async function enrollUser(wallet) {
  try {
    // Create a new CA client for interacting with the CA.
    const caTLSCACerts = ccp.certificateAuthorities['org1-ca'].tlsCACerts.pem;
    const caUrl = ccp.certificateAuthorities['org1-ca'].url;
    const ca = new FabricCAServices(caUrl, { trustedRoots: caTLSCACerts, verify: false }, 'CA');

    // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
    const userExists = await wallet.get(user);
    if (userExists) {
      console.log(`An identity for the client user "${user}" already exists in the wallet`);
    } else {
      // Enroll signing material
      let enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: user, enrollmentSecret: userpw });
      let x509Identity = {
        credentials: {
          certificate: enrollment.certificate,
          privateKey: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
        },
        mspId: mspID,
        type: 'X.509',
      };
      await wallet.put(user, x509Identity);
      console.log(`Successfully enrolled msp for user "${user}" and imported it into the wallet`);

      const tlsca = new FabricCAServices(caUrl, { trustedRoots: caTLSCACerts, verify: false }, `TLSCA`);
      enrollment = await tlsca.enroll({ enrollmentID: user, enrollmentSecret: userpw, profile: 'tls' });
      x509Identity = {
        credentials: {
          certificate: enrollment.certificate,
          privateKey: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
        },
        mspId: mspID,
        type: 'X.509',
      };
      await wallet.put(`${user}-tls`, x509Identity);
      console.log(`Successfully enrolled tls-msp for user "${user}" and imported it into the wallet`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error enrolling user "${user}": ${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

async function startBenchmark(wallet) {
  try {
    const gateway = new Gateway();

    let connectionOptions = {
      identity: `${user}`,
      clientTlsIdentity: `${user}-tls`,
      wallet: wallet,
      discovery: { enabled: false, asLocalhost: false },
    };

    await gateway.connect(ccp, connectionOptions);

    const network = await gateway.getNetwork('channel1');
    const contract = network.getContract('cc-abac');

    let startTime = 0;
    let left = BENCHMARK_OPERATIONS;

    startTime = Date.now();
    while (left > 0) {
      txQueue.push(contract.submitTransaction('invoke', 'a', 'b', '1'));
      left--;
    }

    await txQueue.drain();

    let endTime = Date.now();
    let duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
    let tps = BENCHMARK_OPERATIONS / duration;
    console.log('======== Benchmark finished ========');
    console.log(`Processed ${BENCHMARK_OPERATIONS} ops in ${duration} seconds. TPS: ${tps}`);

    gateway.disconnect();
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Got error:": ${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

async function main() {
  try {
    const wallet = await createWallet();
    await enrollUser(wallet);
    await startBenchmark(wallet);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

main();
```

**Connection Profile:**

```yaml
name: "Network"
version: "1.1"

client:
  organization: Org1

  connection:
    timeout:
      peer:
        endorser: 120
        eventHub: 60
        eventReg: 30
      orderer: 30
    options:
      grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms: 10000

channels:
  channel1:
    orderers:
      - org1-orderer
      - org2-orderer
      - org3-orderer

    peers:
      - org1-peer1
      - org2-peer1
      - org3-peer1

organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP
    peers:
      - org1-peer1
    certificateAuthorities:
      - org1-ca

  Org2:
    mspid: Org2MSP
    peers:
      - org2-peer1
    certificateAuthorities:
      - org2-ca

  Org3:
    mspid: Org3MSP
    peers:
      - org3-peer1
    certificateAuthorities:
      - org3-ca

certificateAuthorities:
  org1-ca:
    url: https://worker2.example.com:30051
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "./crypto/org1-tls-ca-ca-cert.pem"
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    caName: CA

  org2-ca:
    url: https://worker2.example.com:30052
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "./crypto/org2-tls-ca-ca-cert.pem"
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    caName: CA

  org3-ca:
    url: https://worker2.example.com:30053
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "./crypto/org3-tls-ca-ca-cert.pem"
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    caName: CA

orderers:
  org1-orderer:
    url: grpcs://worker2.example.com:30011
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: worker2.example.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "./crypto/org1-tls-ca-ca-cert.pem"

  org2-orderer:
    url: grpcs://worker2.example.com:30012
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: worker2.example.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "./crypto/org2-tls-ca-ca-cert.pem"

  org3-orderer:
    url: grpcs://worker2.example.com:30013
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: worker2.example.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "./crypto/org3-tls-ca-ca-cert.pem"

peers:
  org1-peer1:
    url: grpcs://worker2.example.com:30151
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: worker2.example.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "./crypto/org1-tls-ca-ca-cert.pem"

  org2-peer1:
    url: grpcs://worker2.example.com:30161
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: worker2.example.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "./crypto/org2-tls-ca-ca-cert.pem"

  org3-peer1:
    url: grpcs://worker2.example.com:30171
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: worker2.example.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: "./crypto/org3-tls-ca-ca-cert.pem"
```

**Versions used:**
*HLF:* 2.1
*Node SDK:* 2.2
*Node:* 10.22

Every idea is highly appreciated!

Comment: Is your intention to submit transactions sequentially or concurrently? `BENCHMARK_CONCURRENCY = 1` suggests so but the Promise returned by `submitTransaction()` will be queued for execution from the point it is created so you will be running many transactions in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is generated when no events are received within a timeout window after connecting the event service to receive block events from peers. It's possible that this one peer is not responding but transactions can still flow as there are enough contactable peers for endorsement to be successful. If the logs confirm that all of your peers are communicating correctly and your transactions are all executing OK then probably this error is spurious and you can ignore it.

However, even if the error log is spurious, it would be nice if it wasn't there. It might be that an unsuccessful reconnect is being triggered due to ordering of operations within the `Gateway.disconnect()` process but I'm just guessing here. It might be worth raising a bug report in Jira against the Node SDK for further investigation:

https://jira.hyperledger.org/projects/FABN